# Unable to install azure-cli, unable to find python2-virtualenv

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am trying to install azure cli on AWS linux and getting an error as below. Its got dependency `python2-virtualenv` and I am unable to find the package. Here are the packages that are available with `virtualenv`:

```
$ yum list | grep virtualenv
python26-virtualenv.noarch           15.1.0-1.14.amzn1             amzn-main
python27-virtualenv.noarch           15.1.0-1.14.amzn1             amzn-main
python34-virtualenv.noarch           15.1.0-1.14.amzn1             amzn-main
python35-virtualenv.noarch           15.1.0-1.14.amzn1             amzn-main
python36-virtualenv.noarch           15.1.0-1.14.amzn1             amzn-main
```

Here is the error while installing azure-cli:

```
$ sudo yum install azure-cli
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                             | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.0.67-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python2-virtualenv for package: azure-cli-2.0.67-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: azure-cli-2.0.67-1.el7.x86_64 (azure-cli)
       Requires: python2-virtualenv
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

**Update**

Here is the github issue on this https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9791

Here is the webpage that I followed to install CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest

**Update #2**

I installed python26-virtualenv and create the env to install az_cli inside it. This worked but now I have to be in the environment to use CLI, which is not desirable.

Comment: If you stall using python2?

Comment: python2 not available. I got python26 and python27 available. I dont understand python2 seems like part of version number missing

Comment: Maybe you can try to install it manually, the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: why dont you use pip to install it?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes I did that, I have mentioned in Update #2

Comment: Thanks @CharlesXu that worked. Put that as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, `azure-cli` does not require `python-virtualenv`, you can see the [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/requirements.txt) file of its GitHub repo to know it, as below.

[image]

As @4c74356b41 said in comment, you can install [`azure-cli`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/) by `pip`, because you can find it in PyPI.org.

For example, I created a virtual environment in my Python3 of WSL, you will see I installed `azure-cli` via `pip` after `source bin/activate`, and then to `deactivate` it and set the `PATH` variable with the `az` path via `which az`, I also can use `az` normally.

Fig 1. Create a virtual environment named `az_test` and activate it to install `azure-cli` via `pip`

[image]

Fig 2. After installed, `az` works in the virtual environment.

[image]

Fig 3. There is no requirement for `virtualenv`.

[image]

Fig 4. Even I deactivate the virtual environment, and add the `az` path to `PATH`, it also works

[image]

Finally, you can directly install `azure-cli` in your AWS VM of RHEL7 or CentOS7 via command `sudo pip install azure-cli` when there has been installed `pip` or `pip3` via `yum`.

Hope it helps.